# copy and rename several directory

Tags: linux, bash

If I have several directories, and I want to cp and rename them.

```
#For example. 
> 1st_folder
 >> Case_A
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result
 >> Case_B
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result

> 2nd_folder
 >> Case_A
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result
 >> Case_B
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result
```

I want to copy `Folder_A` `Folder_B` and `Folder_C` , and rename them as `Folder_D` `Folder_E` and `Folder_F` such as below.

```
> 1st_folder
 >> Case_A
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result
   >>> Folder_D_Date_Case       # copy from Folder_A
   >>> Folder_E_Date_Case_work    # copy from Folder_B
   >>> Folder_F_Date_Case_work_Result   # copy from Folder_C
 >> Case_B
   >>> Folder_A_Date_Case
   >>> Folder_B_Date_Case_work
   >>> Folder_C_Date_Case_work_Result
   >>> Folder_D_Date_Case         # copy from Folder_A
   >>> Folder_E_Date_Case_work        # copy from Folder_B
   >>> Folder_F_Date_Case_work_Result    # copy from Folder_C
....
..
.do the same thing as 2nd_folder
```

How  can I do it very quickly using shell script?

Comment: Do you have skeleton of your shell script?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the folders, use parameter expansion to create the new folder name, and use `cp -r` to copy a folder with all its contents.

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in *_folder ; do
    for case in "$dir"/Case_*/ ; do
        for folder in "$case"/Folder*/ ; do
            newname=${folder/Folder_A/Folder_D}
            newname=${newname/Folder_B/Folder_E}
            newname=${newname/Folder_C/Folder_F}
            cp -r "$folder" "${newname}"
        done
    done
done
```

If the contents of Case is more dynamic, i.e. there could be more than 3 subfolders, or names don't follow the same pattern, you'll need to be more specific. Also, in such a case, I'd probably reach for a more expressive language (e.g. Perl).

Comment: thanks for answer, but I wonder that this line `newname=${folder/Folder_A/Folder_D}`  , is `newname/Folder_A/Folder_D` or `folder/Folder_A/Folder_D` ? Sorry just a confirmation.   @choroba

Comment: @Sakura: You start from $folder, you create $newname from it. The first step modifies, $folder, the following steps modify $newname. Only one of the substitutions should be triggered.